# Hierarchical clustering detection with categorical variables in R with missing data

Tags: r, clustering, categorical-data, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to find a hierarchical pattern in categorical data that I have. The data is sort of like this (as I am not allowed to use the actual data, I created a similar problem that follows my own data's structure/question):

I want to investigate sleep and which factors are most important for sleep. As a result, I have a dataset of instances of individuals whose sleep was measured and variables which may influence their sleep. These factors include mattress, last caffeine intake, diet, and noise level. What I want to know: in which (hierarchical) order do these factors influence sleep? I.e. which one is most important and which one least? And is it possible to detect such a hierarchical pattern using categorical variables? It has been suggested to me to use decision tree analysis, but I am struggling to find a way to use this given the NAs in my dataset.

Here is the code I have tried so far in my own dataset, but adjusted for this dummy dataset:

```
####### make dummy df
ind <- c('ind_a', 'ind_b', 'ind_c', 'ind_d', 'ind_e', 'ind_f', 'ind_g', 'ind_h', 'ind_i', 'ind_j')
mattress <- c('soft', 'hard', 'medium', NA, 'very soft', 'medium', 'very soft', 'soft', 'soft', 'hard')
caff <- c(NA, 'morning', 'early afternoon', 'early afternoon', NA, 'evening', 'morning', 'morning', 'no caffeine', 'no caffeine')
diet <- c('omni', NA, 'omni', NA, 'pesc', 'veg', 'veg', 'omni', 'pesc', 'veg')
noise <- c('very loud', 'loud', 'little sound', 'little sound', 'quiet', 'quiet', 'little sound', 'loud', 'quiet', 'little sound')
df <- data.frame(ind = ind, mattress = mattress, caff = caff, diet = diet, noise = noise)
    
#compute distance between variables
library(reshape2)
df$all <- paste(df$mattress, df$caff, df$diet, df$noise, sep = ' ') #since each individual is a specific combination of factors
df <- cbind(df, df[,2:5])
names(df)[7:10] <- c('mattresstype', 'diettype', 'caffeineintake', 'noiselevel') #so that names are not the same
df <- melt(df, id.vars = c('mattresstype', 'diettype', 'caffeineintake', 'noiselevel', 'ind', 'all'))
df$know <- 1 # 1 here indicates that the individual shows this specific trait
mtrx <- acast(df,all ~ value, value.var= "know")
mtrx[is.na(mtrx)] <- 0 # 0 then indicates that the person does not show this trait
rownames(mtrx) <- 1:nrow(mtrx)
dist <- dist(mtrx, method = 'binary', diag=T) #calculate distances binary since binary matrix
hc <- hclust(dist, method = 'ward.D') #Ward method clustering
plot(hc) #see the image below
```

[image]

Each number is thus one individual and its unique combination of 'sleep influencers'. I hope from this dendogram to be able to infer, based on those combinations, which specific influencers are most important based on which individuals are grouped together and where they split in the dendogram.

However, I am not sure that this method will actually be able to inform me about this possible hierarchy in traits that affect sleeping quality (in this case). Could anyone inform me whether this is a proper method and or offer any other suggestions, or if you unlike me have come across a similar post share it? Another option which I tried is to use the cluster package and create a dendogram using the Gower distance (as is suggested here: https://towardsdatascience.com/hierarchical-clustering-on-categorical-data-in-r-a27e578f2995). However, again, my NAs seem to mess with this option.

Many, many thanks and have a nice day :)

Comment: You seem to have confused some methods. Indeed, a decision tree might help you identify factors important for good sleep. But what you did was a hierarchical cluster analysis, which has nothing to do with decision trees. Also, you used a binary distance measure for non-dichotomous variables and Ward analysis with the wrong distance measure. While R will compute anything with numbers in it, your application of the functions leads to nonsensical solutions. You should look into the package `tree` for decision trees or `qca` for QCA.

Comment: @MartinWettstein thanks for your comment! You can indeed see that I was very confused as to which method would be best and that I am a beginner with both. However, what the internet seems to tell me is that creating decision trees would not necessarily work for data with NAs. So far, at least, I have received mostly errors with this. Would you have any recs/knowledge regarding this aspect of decision trees?

Comment: If you replace the NA with a new factor level (e.g.: `"None"`), training decision trees will work. If the NA are mostly randomly distributed over true values, this one factor level should not lead to a better prediction and you will not see them in the decision trees. If they show up somewhere, you had non-random NAs and can decide how to recode them.